# How to use path in this case?

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, command-line

Im trying to use my video with ffmpeg
i run `./stream.sh` and it show this:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x556b31edcfc0] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x556b31edcfc0] moov atom not found
[Parsed_movie_0 @ 0x556b31edc4c0] Failed to avformat_open_input '/home/video.mp4'
[lavfi @ 0x556b31edb200] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'filename=/home/video.mp4:loop=0'
movie=filename=/home/video.mp4:loop=0, setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB): Invalid data found when processing input
```

what wrong with my path?

Comment: ```Invalid data found when processing input``` < Based on this, it looks like your file isn't a valid type that ffmpeg is allowing. What happens when you run the ```file``` command on that file? like what is the output?

Comment: what your 'file' mean? i installed the mp4 filw with wget, and its actually is mp4 file

Comment: Lol, it is a text file, can u tell me how to install a video on linux?

Comment: youru file is `/home/video.mp4:loop=0` ?

Comment: yes it is......